# WPF TabControl: Mouse click event on (empty area of) tab bar

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, event-handling, tabcontrol

In Firefox, double clicking the empty area of the tab bar creates a new tab. I want to implement this feature on WPF TabControl.

But how to handle the mouse click event?

I tried to handle the `MouseDoubleClick` event of TabControl, but unfortunately I got the opposite result: clicking on the empty area of tab bar has no effect, it works only when I click on other areas.

```
    <TabControl MouseDoubleClick="TabControl_DoubleClick">
        ...
    </TabControl>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the event for the TabItem and not the TabControl.For example, this worked for me:

```
private void tabItem1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
           . . .
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what I want is to handle the mouse event of the _empty area_ of tab bar, not tab (TabItem).

Comment: In that case, a hit test would be more appropriate. Look up posts on SO related to hit test captures.

Answer (score 0):

The TabControl contains a `TabPanel`, but even if you attach a Mouse-event to it (it is no control so there is no DoubleClick but you can use MouseUp and check the ClickCount for example) that event will not fire in the "empty space".

The easiest way to do this then might be to copy the default template ([See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx), `Default WPF Themes` link) and add a lookless button or something like it in that area.

Answer (score 0):

Give your "empty space" a background.

In the code below, I've set the `TabItem` control template to a `StackPanel` whose background is not defined. If the `StackPanel` has a background defined, even `Transparent`, you can click on the empty space.

However, if you set the background on the `StackPanel` element itself it will use that background on the selected tab item as well as the unselected items, which is probably not what you want (since background is usually a major way to show which is item selected). So you need to set a trigger for the background for `IsSelected=False`.

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">

    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <StackPanel Name="Panel">
            <Ellipse Margin="0 20 0 10" Height="30" Width="30" Fill="Gray"/>
            <Label Name="Header" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Header" Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```